# AttributeError pywin32

Tags: python, attributeerror, pywin32

I use the pywin32 library since one week to parse visio files to extract shapes and their content. I ran my scripts several times but since yesterday when I execute them I have this error :
`File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 580, in __getattr__ raise AttributeError( AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Visio 16.0 Type Library.IVDocument instance at 0x1943434388768>' object has no attribute 'pages'`

Here is the part of my script which generate the error :

```
import glob
import os
import win32com.client as w32

path = r"C\Users\..." 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.vsd")
visio = w32.Dispatch("visio.Application")

for filename in all_files:
  
    print(filename)
    vdoc = visio.Documents.Open(filename) 
    page = vdoc.pages(1) <-- the problematic line
    shps = page.Shapes
```

I make a list of visio files and after I open them in the for loop I read the first page (they have all one page). The first visio open as well but after I have the error.
I tried to uninstall et reinstall pywin32, I worked in another repertory, change my import name... I tried on another PC and pywin works as well.
I really don't understand why python rise this error now, above all I don't touch this line .
Have you some ideas to resolve this problem ?

Comment: I tried to open file with EnsureDispatch() and DumbDispatch() methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how it works but capitalizing all commands like .Pages/.Type/.Text/.Shapes/.Names because before the commands uncapitatlized .pages/.type/.text/.shapes/.names worked... It's very weird if somebody have an explanation I take it.